# Error when running rubert training on windows

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, text-classification, deeppavlov

When I start training rubert, this message is returned.
I can't even guess what's going wrong...

> > > > model = train_model(config_path) 2021-01-03 18:41:46.694 WARNING in
> > > > 'deeppavlov.dataset_readers.basic_classification_reader'['basic_classification_reader']
> > > > at line 112: Cannot find E:\NTI\valid.csv file 2021-01-03 18:41:47.646
> > > > INFO in
> > > > 'deeppavlov.dataset_iterators.basic_classification_iterator'['basic_classification_iterator']
> > > > at line 74: Splitting field <> to new fields <<['train',
> > > > 'valid']>> [nltk_data] Downloading package punkt to [nltk_data]
> > > > C:\Users\SAM\AppData\Roaming\nltk_data... [nltk_data]   Package punkt
> > > > is already up-to-date! [nltk_data] Downloading package stopwords to
> > > > [nltk_data]     C:\Users\SAM\AppData\Roaming\nltk_data... [nltk_data]
> > > > Package stopwords is already up-to-date! [nltk_data] Downloading
> > > > package perluniprops to [nltk_data]
> > > > C:\Users\SAM\AppData\Roaming\nltk_data... [nltk_data]   Package
> > > > perluniprops is already up-to-date! [nltk_data] Downloading package
> > > > nonbreaking_prefixes to [nltk_data]
> > > > C:\Users\SAM\AppData\Roaming\nltk_data... [nltk_data]   Package
> > > > nonbreaking_prefixes is already up-to-date!
> > > > E:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\h5py_*init*_.py:40: UserWarning: h5py
> > > > is running against HDF5 1.10.5 when it was built against 1.10.4, this
> > > > may cause problems
> > > > '{0}.{1}.{2}'.format(*version.hdf5_built_version_tuple) Warning!
> > > > ***HDF5 library version mismatched error*** The HDF5 header files used to compile this application do not match the version used by the HDF5
> > > > library to which this application is linked. Data corruption or
> > > > segmentation faults may occur if the application continues. This can
> > > > happen when an application was compiled by one version of HDF5 but
> > > > linked with a different version of static or shared HDF5 library. You
> > > > should recompile the application or check your shared library related
> > > > settings such as 'LD_LIBRARY_PATH'. You can, at your own risk, disable
> > > > this warning by setting the environment variable
> > > > 'HDF5_DISABLE_VERSION_CHECK' to a value of '1'. Setting it to 2 or
> > > > higher will suppress the warning messages totally. Headers are 1.10.4,
> > > > library is 1.10.5
> > > > SUMMARY OF THE HDF5 CONFIGURATION
> > > > =================================

### General Information:

```
               HDF5 Version: 1.10.5
              Configured on: 2019-03-04
              Configured by: Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64
                Host system: Windows-10.0.17763
          Uname information: Windows
                   Byte sex: little-endian
         Installation point: C:/Program Files/HDF5
```

### Compiling Options:

```
                 Build Mode:
          Debugging Symbols:
                    Asserts:
                  Profiling:
         Optimization Level:
```

### Linking Options:

```
                  Libraries:
```

Statically Linked Executables: OFF
LDFLAGS: /machine:x64
H5_LDFLAGS:
AM_LDFLAGS:
Extra libraries:
Archiver:
Ranlib:

### Languages:

```
                          C: yes
                 C Compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.16.27023/bin/Hostx86/x64/cl.exe 19.16.27027.1
                   CPPFLAGS:
                H5_CPPFLAGS:
                AM_CPPFLAGS:
                     CFLAGS:  /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W3
                  H5_CFLAGS:
                  AM_CFLAGS:
           Shared C Library: YES
           Static C Library: YES

                    Fortran: OFF
           Fortran Compiler:
              Fortran Flags:
           H5 Fortran Flags:
           AM Fortran Flags:
     Shared Fortran Library: YES
     Static Fortran Library: YES

                        C++: ON
               C++ Compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.16.27023/bin/Hostx86/x64/cl.exe 19.16.27027.1
                  C++ Flags: /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W3 /GR /EHsc
               H5 C++ Flags:
               AM C++ Flags:
         Shared C++ Library: YES
         Static C++ Library: YES

                        JAVA: OFF
               JAVA Compiler:
```

### Features:

```
                   Parallel HDF5: OFF
Parallel Filtered Dataset Writes:
              Large Parallel I/O:
              High-level library: ON
                    Threadsafety: OFF
             Default API mapping: v110
  With deprecated public symbols: ON
          I/O filters (external):  DEFLATE DECODE ENCODE
                             MPE:
                      Direct VFD:
                         dmalloc:
  Packages w/ extra debug output:
                     API Tracing: OFF
            Using memory checker: OFF
 Memory allocation sanity checks: OFF
          Function Stack Tracing: OFF
       Strict File Format Checks: OFF
    Optimization Instrumentation:
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Error message contains the answer:

```
Cannot find E:\NTI\valid.csv file
```

`deeppavlov.dataset_readers.basic_classification_reader` fails to find the file. You need to check paths in your configuration file.